# Approval workflow on list - older items 'fall off' the list. How do I keep them?

Tags: 2013, workflow

Please hang in there with me, I'm  not a SharePoint guru - I have enough knowledge to be dangerous...

I am in a SP2013 environment. Someone in my organization has a list ('Invoice Approvals'). The list shows items that range from current day to about two and a half months ago. This person noticed that after this two and half(ish) months, items no longer appear. They would like to have all of these available for historical purposes.

So... How is this handled? I have gone to the library and looked at the workflow settings, and it tells me that no workflows are associated. When I open the site in SPD, I can see one workflow - 'Publishing Approval'.

Is there a way to make all items stay on this list? If not, is it within the 'Publishing Approval' global workflow that I need to make changes to in order to move items to a new list/library?

I have no doubt I'm missing information that may be vital, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any filters set on the default view that might be filtering out older items?

Comment: Ah yes, I knew I'd forget to add all info needed. I checked the default view earlier and there are no filters at all.

Comment: Do you see paging controls at the bottom of the list? Might they have just moved to a different page?